# First-chance exception: The RPC server is unavailable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, rpc

At some point while developing my C# application, the following started to appear in the VS Output pane whenever I create an OpenFileDialog:

```
First-chance exception at 0x75A6C42D (KernelBase.dll) in (myapp).exe: 0x000006BA: The RPC server is unavailable.
```

I've been maintaining this application for years, and definitely never saw this before, so I started rolling back in SVN to determine when it began.

Bafflingly, revisions in which it occurs & doesn't occur seem to be inconsistent; if I go back sufficiently far it never happens, but there's an "area" when I can check a revision, it won't happen, I'll check another revision, it will, then I'll return to the first, and this time it suddenly will.  In other words, I can't seem to reliably pinpoint when it started happening.

To illustrate this, here's an excerpt of my tests, indented for clarity. Numbers are revisions. For each test, I "update to revision" and do a full rebuild.

```
      3977: Exception. This is the most-recent revision.
 3839: OK.  Since it didn't happen, I'll start working my way back up to see when it starts
   3843: OK
    3852: OK
     3890: Exception. So it started between 3852 & 3890.
    3852: Exception. Huh?? I JUST tried 3852, and last time it didn't happen!
3778: OK. Going back this far, I've never seen it happen.
    3852: Exception. I guess I'll start working my way BACK to see when it stops.
   3828: Exception
  3810: OK
   3828: Exception.  Just making sure.
  3810: OK. Just making sure again.
   3828: OK.  What?? 3828 showed the exception last time I tried!
    3852: OK. (but previously it showed the exception)
     3890: Exception
```

I'm aware that I can just tell VS not to break on these types of exceptions, and ignore them.  But as mentioned, after years of working on this software, I've never seen it once - so I'd like to determine exactly *when* and *why* they started, rather than just turning a blind eye.

Comment: From your test it seems to be "random", so probably the error is not in your code. As RPC is calling remote resource, check your network, RPC server activity etc. For example domain authentication can cause this.

Comment: It happens with all network connections off.  Also, what's strange is that it NEVER seems to happen with sufficiently old builds (i.e.  revisions around 3700 or so), and it ALWAYS happens on the very current revisions. So while it doesn't *seem* like it's in my code...it still seems nonsensical to me that it would behave like this. Why would I be able to stop it by rolling back revisions, and start it by rolling forwards -but the precise revisions at which it happens & doesn't are so unpredictable?

Comment: Try to rebuild single version multiple times, is the result always the same or each build behave differently?

Comment: I just tried 14 rebuilds: r3982 (current) did it every time (7/7 in a row), r3783 (old) never did it (0/7).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your project.  When you use the shell dialogs, like OpenFileDialog, you load Explorer into your process.  Which comes with a lot of baggage, you *also* get all of the shell extensions loaded.  The kind that customize Explorer, they work just as well in the dialog.

Misbehaving ones are quite common.  Programmers tend to use the quirkier kind.  Any mishap in such a shell extension is now visible to you, the debugger tells you about it.

So, nothing actually went wrong, the exception was caught and handled.  Explorer implements counter-measures against bad shell extensions destabilizing it and automatically disables them.  So you just have a lame-duck shell extension that doesn't work, low odds you'd notice since it probably hasn't worked for a while.

The debugger can tell you which one is bad.  Enable unmanaged debugging and tick the Thrown checkboxes in the Debug + Exception dialog.  The debugger will now stop when the exception is thrown.  You won't see any source code but you can look at the Call Stack debugger window for hints.  It displays the name of the DLL that contain the bad code somewhere on the stack, below the Windows DLL functions.  The name ought to give you a hint which one is the troublemaker.  SysInternals' AutoRuns utility is excellent to disable them.

Comment: Hmm, good insight.  However, (1) I don't recall having added any even remotely recently (I'm pretty anal about what gets installed on my system, and (2) If it has nothing at all to do with the project, doesn't it seem very weird that rolling revisions back would have any effect on whether or not this appears? Changing revisions wouldn't change which explorer extensions are present, so I'd expect it to either always appear or never - regardless of which revision I'm debugging.  No?

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell nothing looks obviously fishy in the call stack.  All MS DLLs it seems: http://screencast.com/t/VI1jPAQY0aH

Comment: davclnt.dll doesn't belong in your process.  Well, not that easy to get rid of.  Flip the ignore bit.

Comment: ...I was playing with WebDAV a few months back.  Still, I fail to see why this would only come up when running some revisions but not others.  I just tried 14 times in a row: rebuilt r3982 7x in a row, and it showed the exception every time; rebuilt r3783 7x in a row, and it never did.  And as per the original question, some revisions are inconsistent.  An exception like this seems like it should be consistently reproducable - and if it has nothing to do with my code, should not be affected by the revision I'm using.

Comment: In my case it was obsolete drive mappings that were causing the problem. The results are inconsistent because the drive mapping failure results are cached. Remove broken drive mappings from "This PC" using File Explorer and the errors will go away.